# Expected value of pulling the same colored ball 2 times succesively

Tags: probability

If there is $20$ balls from which $12$ $red$ and $8$ $blue$ and you draw with replacement until the last two have the same color, what is the expected value of the number of draws needed to succeed? Which model should I choose? I tried with $geometric$ $distribution$ setting $p = p_{red}*p_{red} + p_{blue}*p_{blue}$. Then calculated its mean value, but then I wrote a program wich I believe is correct, and I don't get the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you drawing with or without replacement?

Comment: with replacement, I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the number of draws needed to succeed. Calculate 
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X>k)= 2+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \mathbb P(X>k).
$$
What is $\mathbb P(X>k)$? It is the probability that in first $k$ draws colors are constantly changing. This probability depends whether $k$ is odd or even.

Let $k=2m$ is even. Then 
$$
\mathbb P(X>k) = \mathbb P(\underbrace{rbrbrb\ldots rb}_{m \text{ red and } m \text{ blue}})+\mathbb P(\underbrace{brbrbr\ldots br}_{m \text{ red and } m \text{ blue}}) = 2\left(\frac{12}{20}\right)^m \left(\frac{8}{20}\right)^m = 2\cdot 0.24^m.
$$
Let $k=2m+1$ is odd. Then 
$$
\mathbb P(X>k) = \mathbb P(\underbrace{rbrbr\ldots br}_{m+1 \text{ red and } m \text{ blue}})+\mathbb P(\underbrace{brbrb\ldots br}_{m \text{ red and } m+1 \text{ blue}}) $$
$$= \left(\frac{12}{20}\right)^{m+1} \left(\frac{8}{20}\right)^m+\left(\frac{12}{20}\right)^m \left(\frac{8}{20}\right)^{m+1} = 0.24^m.
$$
So 
$$
\mathbb E[X] = 2+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \mathbb P(X>k) = 2+\sum_{m=1}^\infty 2\cdot 0.24^m+\sum_{m=1}^\infty  0.24^m = 2+ 2\cdot \frac{0.24}{1-0.24} + \frac{0.24}{1-0.24} = 2+\frac{18}{19} = \frac{56}{19}.
$$